# What Are NServiceBus 3.0 Minimum Requirements

Tags: nservicebus, minimum-requirements

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find any up to date information on the minimum requirements of NServiceBUs 3.0. I did find some posts that go back to 2011, are they still relevant? does anyone have a link or info on this.

more specifically we're trying to install on a server with Windows 2003 sp1 on it. But as far as I can make out I need MSMQ 3.1 which was released in SP2

cheers

Johnny

Answer (score 0):

The minimum version of MSMQ required to run NServiceBus v3 is MSMQ 3.1.
Obviously you also need .NET4 and DTC installed.

For your information, if you do a search on the [NServiceBus website](http://particular.net/nservicebus) you would get the answer :), see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/running-on-windows